# I want to get the last number of a double digit number but TypeError 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' happens

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to get Python to print out the last number of a double digit number, but it keeps telling me 'TypeError 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**''. What can I do to fix this?

```
def lucky(firstn,lastn,c):
    if len('firstn')>1:
        c = len('firstn')*len('lastn')*3
        return c[-1]

firstname = raw_input('Enter your first name: ')
lastname = raw_input('Enter your last name: ')
f = len(firstname)*len(lastname)*3
print lucky(firstname,lastname,f)
```

Comment: You had better to read some basic introduction about Python first. In function, all of the arguments are not used, is that right? c is an int, it doesn't has the method `getitem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers and strings are not the same things in Python. If you have one but want the other, you need to use `int` or `str` to explicitly convert between them. The last digit of a number (as a string) is `str(n)[-1]`. If you want the digit as a number, wrap that whole thing in `int()`.

You're also confusing variables with their names, it seems, since your function is using the strings `'firstn'` and `'lastn'` instead of the value stored in the variables of those names. Get rid of the quotes if you want the variables!